# Link based stack in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures

I've been trying to figure out how to create link based stack and came across a snippet of code that I don't quite understand.

```
int pop()
{
    // If the stack is empty return a sentinel value
    if (isEmpty())
        return -999;

    // Get the data to return from the top of the stack
    int intReturn = top->info;

    // Create a pointer to keep track of the top node
    IntSLLNode *temp;
    temp = top;

    // Move the top of the stack to the next element
    // or null if there is no next element
    top = top->next;

    // Free up memory
    delete temp;

    // Send back the data
    return intReturn;
    ...
}
```

I understand up until `top=top->next`.

1) What was the point of creating a temp node if we never really use it?

2) By moving the top pointer to the next node, are we deleting the former top node? Thus popping it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `temp` is needed because we will need the old value of `top` after `top` is moved in order to free the memory of the node being popped. We have to move `top` then free the memory; if we try to do it the other way around (free memory, then move `top`) then we would have to use a temporary variable to hold `top->next` (as that would have been lost in this scenario). In either case, you can't avoid a temporary variable.

2) Moving `top` results in promoting the second node to the top node, and removing the top node from the stack (which is half of what we expect from `pop` - the other half being returning the value of the popped node). The node is not deleted until `delete temp`, which is why we needed to preserve it.

Comment: that kind of makes sense but I'm not quite following. Is it the action of promoting the 2nd to the top node what deletes the node, or is it when we delete temp, which is the old node at this point?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "delete the node". If you understand it correctly (as "deallocate its memory"), then it is `delete temp`. If you understand it as "remove it from stack", then it is changing the top of the stack to the second node in stack.